# Rip all video clips from a DVD using VLC Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, dvd, ripping

I have some old DVDs with family videos on them. When I play one of the DVDs, I get a menu where I can play one of many video clips. However when I use VLC’s ‘Convert/Save’ tool to rip the DVD contents to my Windows 10 computer, I only get one of the video clips from the DVD.

VLC seems to be working on all the clips, because the converting progress bar will go through several rounds of loading, and will work for several minutes.  I tried with the ‘no DVD menu’ checkbox both on and off, and kept all of the other default settings the same.

Ideally I’d like to get folder with every video clip from my DVD inside. How can I accomplish something like this with VLC?

Answer (score 3):

My opinion: Don't bother with VLC.

Use [MakeMKV](https://makemkv.com/) instead.

With MakeMKV you can literally rip every DVD title from the disk, without re-encoding them and potentially losing quality, in one step. It isn't CPU intensive (no conversion) and takes only as long as it takes to read the disk.

It's as simple as selecting all the titles you want, pointing it at a directory to export to, and then waiting. All the titles will be exported to individual files.

Comment: The only downside of this is the relatively large filesize you get with this, so you probably need to do transcoding to save some space as a single DVD is about 7GB without transcoding.